# Haskell: Random number

Tags: haskell

I have written a function to get a pair from [-10,10] by random.

```
import System.Random


main = 
    do { 
         s <- randomNumber
       ; b <- randomNumber
       ; print (head s,head b)}
randomNumber :: IO [Int]
randomNumber = sequence $ replicate 1 $ randomRIO (-10,10)
```

Now I want to take a list like [(1,2),(2,3),(2,3)], all the number is come from the randomNumber. How can I do that? I don't know how to achieve that.

I have tried to use state to get random, but somehow I can't use state on my computer.
I did this :

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad.State
randomSt :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => State g a
randomSt = State random
```

But when I compiled it, it showed: Not in scope: data constructor ‘State’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if all you want is a function

```
  randomPairs :: IO [(Int, Int)]
```

then we can do something like

```
   randomList :: IO [Int]
   randomList = randomRs (-10, 10) `fmap` newStdGen
   randomPairs = ??? randomList randomList
```

where `???` takes two `IO [Int]` and "zips" them together to form a `IO [(Int, Int)]`. We now turn to [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and query for a function `[a] -> [a] -> [(a, a])` and we find a function `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]` we now just need to "lift" `zip` into the `IO` monad to work with it across `IO` lists so we end up with

```
  randomPairs = liftM2 zip randomList randomList
```

or if we want to be really fancy, we could use applicatives instead and end up with

```
  import Control.Applicative

  randomPairs = zip <$> randomList <*> randomList
```

But judging from your `randomNumber` funciton, you really just want *one* pair. The idea is quite similar. Instead of generating a list, we generate just one random number with `randomRIO (-10, 10)` and lift `(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)` resulting in

```
  randomPair = (,) <$> randomRIO (-10, 10) <*> randomRIO (-10, 10)
```

Finally, the `State` data constructor went away a while ago because the MTL moved from having separate `State` and `StateT` types to making `State` a type synonym. Nowadays you need to use the lowercase `state :: (s -> (s, a)) -> State s a`

To clarify, my final code is

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad

randomList :: IO [Int]
randomList = randomRs (-10, 10) `fmap` newStdGen

pairs :: IO [(Int, Int)]
pairs = liftM2 zip randomList randomList

somePairs n = take n `fmap` pairs

main = somePairs 10 >>= print
```

Comment: As you can see, I have imported Control.Monad.State, then I still can't use it.

Comment: Hi, your code passed the compile, but when I run it, it shows out of memory. Looks like there is something wrong of the randomList?

Comment: @Xie Indeed, I've updated to take advantage of `newStdGen` and `randomRs`, how that works should be pretty clear from the types

Comment: Hi, this new code actually get the same number for every pair. I change your last code to     `randomList = sequence . replicate 1$ randomRIO (-10, 10)

randomPairs = zip <$> randomList <*> randomLis` , it get a great pair. Actually, I would like to get n pairs for [-10,10], and the n is under control. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Like `take n randomPairs`, but looks like the type is error

Comment: @Xie Can you clarify "gets the same number for every pair" trying this out in GHCi I'm getting different pairs. and you'll need `take n `fmap` pairs` and not to use the `replicate 1` thingy since taht will only generate one pair.

Comment: Ah, sorry, maybe somewhere is wrong when I type it, now I get different number in one pair.